# Apache Kafka KRaft - Kafka Storage Tool

Tags: apache-kafka

in the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/config/kraft/README.md) it is mentioned that:

> As described above in the QuickStart section, you must use the kafka-storage.sh tool to generate a cluster ID for your new cluster, and then run the format command on each node before starting the node.

**Generate a cluster ID**

```
./bin/kafka-storage.sh random-uuid
xtzWWN4bTjitpL3kfd9s5g
```

**Format Storage Directories**

```
./bin/kafka-storage.sh format -t <uuid> -c ./config/kraft/server.properties
Formatting /tmp/kraft-combined-logs
```

would be it a problem to generate the `<uuid>` with a different program and not with the `kafka-storage.sh` one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It needs to be a type-4 UUID that doesn't match Kafka's internal UUIDs

From Kafka source-code

```java
    /**
     * Static factory to retrieve a type 4 (pseudo randomly generated) UUID.
     */
    public static Uuid randomUuid() {
        java.util.UUID uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID();
        while (uuid.equals(METADATA_TOPIC_ID_INTERNAL) || uuid.equals(ZERO_ID_INTERNAL)) {
            uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID();
        }
        return new Uuid(uuid.getMostSignificantBits(), uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/StorageTool.scala , for easy reference

Comment: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/c2ea0c2e1d44332639214b921ddf3dc1edf478c0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/Uuid.java